# Making submodule in topmodule results in verilator error

Tags: verilog, verilator

I just started learning Verilog and decided to make a 4 bit adder. To create this 4 bit adder, I first built a half_adder module, then a full_adder module which uses the half_adder module. In the 4 bit adder I use 4 full_adder modules.
Up to this point everything compiles and simulates with Verilator. I wrote some tests and checked that all outputs were correct.

After being done with the 4 bit adder, I thought of creating a small ALU which uses the 4 bit adder for additions. Now when I create a submodule of the 4 bit adder in the ALU module, I get verilator errors.

The 4 bit adder looks like:

```
`default_nettype none
module adder_4_bit(
    i_a,
    i_b,
    o_sum,
    o_carry
);

    input   [3:0]   i_a;
    input   [3:0]   i_b;
    output  [3:0]   o_sum;
    output  wire    o_carry;

    wire    internal_carry1;
    wire    internal_carry2;
    wire    internal_carry3;

    full_adder full_adder1(
        .i_a        ( i_a[0] ),
        .i_b        ( i_b[0] ),
        .i_carry    ( 1'b0 ),
        .o_sum      ( o_sum[0] ),
        .o_carry    ( internal_carry1 )
    );

    full_adder full_adder2(
        .i_a        ( i_a[1] ),
        .i_b        ( i_b[1] ),
        .i_carry    ( internal_carry1 ),
        .o_sum      ( o_sum[1] ),
        .o_carry    ( internal_carry2 )
    );

    full_adder full_adder3(
        .i_a        ( i_a[2] ),
        .i_b        ( i_b[2] ),
        .i_carry    ( internal_carry2 ),
        .o_sum      ( o_sum[2] ),
        .o_carry    ( internal_carry3 )
    );

    full_adder full_adder4(
        .i_a        ( i_a[3] ),
        .i_b        ( i_b[3] ),
        .i_carry    ( internal_carry3 ),
        .o_sum      ( o_sum[3] ),
        .o_carry    ( o_carry )
    );
endmodule
```

The ALU (for now) looks like this. I still need to implement the optcode select etc, but even creating the 4 bit adder submodule already resulted in errors...:

```
`default_nettype none
module alu_4_bit(
    i_a,
    i_b,
    i_opt,
    o_result,
    o_status
);

    input [3:0] i_a;
    input [3:0] i_b;
    input [3:0] i_opt;
    output [3:0] o_result;
    output [4:0] o_status;

    adder_4_bit adder_4_bit_inst(
        .i_a(i_a),
        .i_b(i_b),
        .o_sum(o_result),
        .o_carry(o_status[0])
    );
endmodule
```

When running the command
`verilator -Wall -cc alu_4_bit.v`

I get the following errors:

```
verilator -Wall -cc alu_4_bit.v 
%Error: adder_4_bit:5: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:11: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:27: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:28: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:31: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:40: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:44: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:58: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:60: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:66: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:70: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:72: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:78: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:79: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:81: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:86: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:93: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:119: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:121: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:124: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:131: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:132: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:133: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:134: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:135: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:139: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:141: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:143: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:144: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:146: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:148: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:150: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:157: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:160: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:162: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:164: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:165: Unterminated string
%Error: adder_4_bit:1: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
%Error: Exiting due to 38 error(s)
%Error: Command Failed /usr/local/bin/verilator_bin -Wall -cc alu_4_bit.v
```

The strange thing is that these errors seem to come from the adder_4_bit.v while I already compiled and simulated it with verilator. I even made sure it worked correctly.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get such warnings when I tried to compile it with verilator, however I got some other warnings:

```
alu_4_bit.v:12: Signal is not used: i_opt
```

I commented out `input[3:0] i_opt` and i_opt's definition in module I/O and then I got this warning.

```
%Error: alu_4_bit.v:20: Illegal bit or array select; type does not have a bit range, or bad dimension: type is logic
```

I replaced `output[3:0] o_status` with `output o_status` and removed the bit select from `.o_carry(o_status[0])` so that it is `.o_carry(o_status)` now.

After these, the design compiled with my version (4.004) of verilator. I hope these help you as well.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it does compile and the problem is not in the verilog code. I run verilator version 4.010. Because the problem was not in the verilog code, I tried to move all my code to a different directory, this solved my problem! The directory I was trying to compile in, already had previous compiled code in there, this might have been interfering?